# Testing a fake repository

Tags: entity-framework, tdd, repository-pattern

I've been looking at various approaches to implementing the repository pattern with EF, specifically using a generic repository.

I had been trying to use an IRepository that would have an IContext property, so that the only difference between any implementation of the IRepository would be the context.  I've found this difficult enough that I've abandoned the "fake context" approach, and now just have a dictionary of List as my "context" in the fake repository:

```
public Dictionary<Type, object> _sets = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
```

And to manipulate it, would do something like this in the fake:

```
public void Add<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        var set = _sets[typeof (T)] as IQueryable<T>;
        var updatedSet = set.ToList();
        updatedSet.Add(entity);
        _sets[typeof (T)] = updatedSet.AsQueryable<T>();
    }
```

In the real repository, I can just use:

```
void Add<T>(T entity)
    {
        Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }
```

In my Update method, I would have to have similarly different implementations to accomodate a real context inheriting DbContext, and a fake using a collection-based approach.

This approach is making me nervous.  As others have mentioned in other questions, now my repository implementations are so different, that I don't feel I can trust a test until it's been run with both a fake and real repository.

Am I just a noob that is overthinking this?  Or is there a better way to implement a fake context that behaves more like a DbContext so I don't have to have such drastically different classes implementing the repository interface?

**To summarize:** I understand the advantages of testing with an in-memory repository.  My question is, when I have to make two implementations of the repository that are this different, does that mean that I am doing something wrong, or is this just the cost of testing with fakes, and if the logic tests pass, I shouldn't sweat it so much?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what we did in the project I'm working on: We have a repository wrapper class around EF so that way we can use mocks in the unit testing when it's needed. I considered doing an in memory repository like you're doing, but I ended up deciding against it because I only really needed it for doing querying. However, since Linq To Entities is a subset of Linq to Objects. A unit test might pass, but then fail the integration test since you might have been using functionality not part of Linq to Entities. If I need to integration test that query and couldn't trust the unit test, it didn't feel like it made sense to do both.

For unit testing, I just had a mock of the repository and verified that the appropriate method (Insert or whatever) had been called. For integration testing for deleting/insert/whatever, just hit the actual database.

For the actual querying, I just did integration testing. I moved the query to a separate function. My code would call that function to retrieve the query results and I could just integration test the function with the query in it separately and unit test the processing of the query results.

I don't know if that made sense or if there's a better way to do it, but that's what I ended up doing.

**Alternatively, if you want to continue with the in-memory implementation**
I think you should be able to do the following:

Just have a list of objects and use the OfType to return the correct type:

```
public TEntity Get<TEntity>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where, params System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties) where TEntity : class
{
    return _repositories.OfType<TEntity>().AsQueryable().Where(where).FirstOrDefault();
}

public TEntity Insert<TEntity>(TEntity tEntity) where TEntity : class
{
    _repositories.Add(tEntity);
    return tEntity;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will probably get to mocking, but I'm trying to get my hands dirty at each step, so for now am just sticking with the approach of in-memory for the fake, and EF context for the real data.

I was trying your approach yesterday, but it took me a couple of failed tests to realize I can't add to a set that is typed IQueryable.  Your comment did lead me to realize that I don't need to add a set as IQueryable, though.  Now, I just add the set as a list - makes Add/Update/Delete cleaner, and I can use a method QuerySet<T> to return the list as IQueryable when I need it to query in my test.